# Postgresql Table column, how to convert Unixtimestamp into readable timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I got a Table in Postgres where is a column which has plenty unixtimestamps in it. For example: 1535753230

How can I convert this whole column into human readable timestamp? 
(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)

thanks for your time!

Comment: Use `to_timestamp` to turn it into a `timestamp with time zone`. You can format that with `to_char`.

Comment: use the to_timestamp() function e.g. `SELECT to_timestamp(column) FROM table`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out !:)

Comment: 2018-09-01 00:06:56+02 is my result. I just want the timestamp to go till 56 without +02. How could I format it without +02? thank you!

Comment: `select to_timestamp(1535753230)::timestamp;` But why do you want that?

Comment: i just want a readable timestamp :D 
thanks all for your answers !

Comment: Still, because Unix time is referring to UTC, just cutting of the +02 is not necessarily want you want: `select to_timestamp(1535753230) at time zone 'utc'`